# Setting up media file access on AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

Im using **boto3** and **django-storage** libraries for apload media files of my django project.

**storage_backends.py**

```
 class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_STORAGE_LOCATION
    default_acl = 'private'
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False

class PublicStaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_PUBLIC_STATIC_LOCATION
```

**settings.py**

```
AWS_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'media/private'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_PUBLIC_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'path.to.PrivateMediaStorage'
```

models.py

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    """ uploaded documents"""

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    filename = models.CharField(_('documents name'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    datafile = models.FileField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Doctype, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

File loading works well. But there is a point I don't understand, and the link to the file looks wrong (it contains static instead of media). Looks like

```
https://myhost.s3.amazonaws.com/static/class-descriptions_1.csv
```

And else about access. Now that I click on the link to the file, I get a message

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>4B8296F8F77491F5</RequestId>
<HostId>
CG96q+LGWcvsIK2YkuaE2wExL8/YTqH1PmjOSFGAqcgaKaTYnOet1QoItGJhW1Oj
</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is normal for unregistered users, but how do I allow users registered in my Django project to see this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use pre-signed URLs to implement this functionality. All users can access S3 objects if the bucket is public. If you want to restrict access, then the bucket has to be private and you need to generate pre-signed URLs per user.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

Answer (score 1):

To make the media urls come from a different place, you need to override `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'path.to.PrivateMediaStorage'
```

Secondly, if you haven't defined `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` in settings, then the files will use ACL inherited from the bucket. Probably bucket has been created with ACL private. Thats why the files can't be accessed.

Finally, regarding the access error. If the ACL is private, then no one can access it apart from the owner. So you need to change the ACL of the directories. You can use [**`s3tools`**](https://s3tools.org/usage) for that. For example:

```
s3cmd setacl --recursive s3://<bucket-name> --acl-public
```

Also

> This is normal for unregistered users, but how do I allow users registered in my Django project to see this file?

Thats not how ACL works. ACL access needs to be set from S3 bucket. So you can't forbid user from accessing the contents from bucket if ACL is set to `public-read`.

*As per @vikyol's answer, there is a way to send pre-signed URLs to user.*

For more information on Canned ACL, please check the [**`documentation`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) by amazon.

Comment: I have a DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE at settings.py. Else I have AWS_DEFAULT_ACL=None, after removing this values I got access to the downloaded files, but the files are still uploaded to the static folder and are therefore available to everyone.