# How to protect the Django media url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, media

In my code I know how to protect my `endpoint url`. I can do simply like this

```py
class ApprovalViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                      mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApprovalSerializer
```

**Problem:**
However, my challenging task is I need to change `/media` url every time since it is sensitive files. And my files are stored in AWS S3

**Questions:**
1. How to protect the `/media` url in Django
2. My workaround is keep changing the `url`. How can I do that?

Comment: You should upload to S3 with a private ACL and then sign the requests which load the content so you have to be authorised to view the content.

Comment: try to using djfiler https://pypi.org/project/djfiler/

Comment: @markwalker_ I know `ACL` = Access Control Level. But `sign the requests` I don't understand this. Please give me more clue to go. I will share my answer based on your comment here

Comment: @sinafarhadi https://sinafarhadi.ir/How-To-Upload-Files-In-Django/
broken screenshot url

Comment: @sarit https://github.com/E-RROR/djfiler

Comment: @sanit i test it now but i dont see any broken url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@markwalker_ Thank you very much for your comment. Here is my answer. `res` variable here is sloppy since it can be `None` and raises the error. I will add my exception definition later on this problem

Put `private` in `settings.py`
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response
```

Then I have to `override` method `to_representation`

```
class AWSImageField(serializers.ImageField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        # `media/` is `MEDIA_URL`, but it is being used with `public-config`. I don't want to mess up the common use case
        url = create_presigned_url(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, 'media/' + value.name)
        if url is not None:
            res = requests.get(url)

        return res.url
```

**References:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

[Setting up media file access on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520553/setting-up-media-file-access-on-aws-s3)

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html