# How to change nested serializer based on DEBUG?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, nested

I have nested serializer like this

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(...):
    image1 = ImageSerializer()
    image2 = ImageSerializer()
    image3 = ImageSerializer()
```

When I need to comply with ISO and my feature is carrying on sensitive data
So I have to use short term `MEDIA_URL`. The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767269/how-to-protect-the-django-media-url)

**Problem:**
I use `DEBUG=True` to do local development and `serializer` is using one another nested class

**Question:**
1. What is the best practice to change nested serializer based on `settings.DEBUG`?

**Workaround:**
Refactor with `Mixin` and use `.get_serializer_class` in the `ViewSet` to pick `serializer_class` based on `DEBUG` value

Comment: You need to override get_serializer_class method and supply the DEBUG param

Comment: Why do you need to use a different serialiser and not just set a different MEDIA_URL?